# Uber Supplier API oauth not returning a terms and accept button diabled

Tags: uber-api

I am implementing oauth2 for uber supplier [api](https://developer.uber.com/docs/vehicles/references/api/v1/supplier-performance-data/get-drivers-information). But the authorization URL returns a page with no information and Accept button disabled.

Did anyone come across such a problem or have been able to integrate uber suppliers api?

[image]